# Using Bootstrap 3, how do you add html to a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have been having trouble getting HTML into a tooltip using bootstrap 3.  I have scoured the internet and tried (seemingly) everything, but it's not working.  I will put my code below, but basically what's happening is when I hover over the link, it's generating a tooltip with no HTML, but it's also placing the same text onto the webpage itself.  When I leave the hover, the tooltip (with no html) dissappears, but the text on the webpage remains.  Can anyone help?  My code is below...
   The version of bootstrap (js and css) I am using is 3.3.7.
   The version of jquery is 3.1.0

Thanks for the help.  Also, I couldn't find "Bootstrap-3" for a tag, so I had to use twitter-bootstrap.  Sorry if that causes confusion, but the version of bootstrap I am using is listed in the question (3.3.7).

HTML Code

```
    <link href="static/css/opendcs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="static/js/blah.js"></script> 
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
<legend class="legendFooter noBottomMargin noBorders">Upload Rating Table</legend>
<legend></legend>
  <div class="container blah">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <input type=file name=file>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type=submit value=Upload>

    <a id="additionalInfoToolTip" href="#" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="Here is a title" target="_blank">Additional Information</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

blah.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "Page is ready." );
    //$('#additionalInfoToolTip').tooltip();
    $('#additionalInfoToolTip').tooltip({
        selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
      });
/*
  $('#additionalInfoToolTip').tooltip({
    selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
  })

  $('.tooltip-demo.well').tooltip({
  selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
})
*/
    $(function () {
        /*
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      })
      */
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a complete CSS tooltip

```css
.wrap{
  padding: 100px
}
.tooltip{
  background: #fa0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Needed css */
.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
        
.tooltip::after{
content: attr(data-title); /* <= dynamically title content */
z-index: 22;
 position: absolute;
 top: -35px;
 left: -27px;
 min-width: 60px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 font-size: 70%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 20px;
 opacity: 0;
}

.tooltip::before{ /* For the arrow */
  content: '';
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #111;
 position: absolute;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: -18px;
 left: 8px;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<span class="tooltip" data-title="Tool tip text">
Main text
</span>

<span class="tooltip" data-title="Another Tool tip text">
AnotherMain text
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm...That's a fair point.  I am trying to get a certain look, but I can definitely get that look with an all css tooltip.  Thanks.  Sometimes you get so much tunnel vision to solve a problem that you forget the simpler option.

Comment: You are welcome! you can readjust the arrow by tweaking the **position** `left, right, top and bottom`  of the `::before` pseudo code. Happy coding!